# 2 querys dependientes mongo nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

tengo un metodo que hace un primer query a la bd y trae un resultado(ese funciona bien), luego utilizo ese resultado para hacer otro query y se me cae, no me llega el resultado...

```
 async function foo() {
        let primerProceso = await ListarSupervisores();
        let segundoProceso = await ListarSupervisores2proceso(primerProceso);

    }
```

esta es la primera funcion que me retorna el resultado deseado y lo almaceno en una variable para luego utilizarlo en la segunda funcion...

```
 async function ListarSupervisores() {

        return new Promise(resolve => {
            Evaluations.aggregate([
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": {
                            "domainLogin": "$domainLogin"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "domainLogin": "$_id.domainLogin",
                        "_id": 0
                    }
                }
            ], (err, registrosEncontrados) => {
                if (!err) {

                    resolve(registrosEncontrados)

                } else {
                    console.log('hola')
                    reject(err)
                }
            }
            )
        });
```

luego llamo a la segnda funcion con el resultado de la primera y hago otro query...

```
async function ListarSupervisores2proceso(valor) {

                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const valoresABuscar = valor.map(item=> item.domainLogin)

        Workers.find({'DomainLogin':{$in:valoresABuscar}}, (err, datos)=> {
             if( err) reject(err)
             resolve(datos)

        })


})
```

foo()

solo me trae un registro, y son varios...

Comment: Por favor haz un `console.log(valor)` y dime lo que te sale.

Comment: angel eres un gennio, gracias de verdad, de un venezolano en chile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que te retorne el resultado en la segunda función, despues del `forEach` debes agregar `resolve(segundaSalida)`

Después debes usar solo un query para obtener todo:

> Este código esta echo sobre la marcha y no esta probado

```
async function ListarSupervisores2proceso(valor) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const valoresABuscar = valor.map(item=> item.domainLogin)

        Workers.find({'DomainLogin':{$in:valoresABuscar}}, (err, datos)=> {
             if( err) reject(err)
             resolve(datos)

        })


})
```

De la manera que lo estas haciendo con `forEach` en cada iteracion estas creando una nueva promesa y para que eso te funcione tendrias que crear un arreglo de promesas de la siguiente manera:

```
const arregloDePromesas = []

 valor.forEach((item) =>{


       const promesa = Workers.find({ 'DomainLogin': item.domainLogin }) ).exec()

       arregloDePromesas.push(promesa)
})

//Cuando ya tienes todas las promesas listas las ejecutas asi:

return Promise.all(arregloDePromesas)
 .then(datos=> resolve(datos))
 .catch(err=>reject(err))
```

La diferencia es que `datos` te devuelve un arreglo por cada promesa ejecutada y como ves es un poco mas laborioso. En tu caso utilizas la misma `query` cada vez y no tiene mucho sentido hacerlas por separado.

Comment: solo me trae un solo registro

Comment: @rrodo1310 Actualice la pregunta..

Comment: listo y disculpa la molestia estoy comenzando en node, gracias por tu pronta respuesta

Comment: @rrodo1310 Estamos para ayudar! Ntp. Así empezamos todos.

Comment: eres un genio, gracias de todo corazon

Comment: bendiciones me fuiste de gran ayuda

Comment: @rrodo1310 si la respuesta fue útil, te invito a marcarla como válida. Es la mejor forma de dar las gracias. Saludos